# logs regex matching issue

Tags: python, regex

```
reLogExtractor = re.compile(# parse over "date mumble process[pid]: [mumble." (PID is optional)
        r'.*?\s[\w\-\.]*?(\[\d*\])?:\s*\[[\d*\]]*\]*'
                       # any of the following
        r'(?:'
        r'(?P<logError>EMERG|EMERGENCY|ERR|ERROR|CRIT|CRITICAL|ALERT)|'
        r'(?P<logWarning>WARN|WARNING)|'
                       r'(?P<logNotice>NOTICE)|'
                       r'(?P<logNormal>[^\]]*)'
                       # close'm, parse over the "]"
                       r')\]')
```

using this regex I am trying match below sentences `log1,log2,log3` but
`log1` is matching other two giving none.

```
log1="Jun 23 08:29:13 blr-00 rscored[0000]: [ocd.auth_helper.WARNING] Error in message from 24214211.lab.heewt.com for server failed due to HTTPSConnectionPool(host='24214211.lab.htretr.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/cmc.auth/1.0/certificate (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)"
```

```
log2="Jun 7 12:42:02 brr-00 interceptor [0000]: [cluster/reader/[fdos:d7e2:2d90:1904::8]:7850-> [fd08:d7e2:2d90:1902::3]:15101.ERR] - {- -} Error reading header from [fd08:d7e2:2d90:1904::8]:7850: Connection reset by peer"
```

```
log3="Jun 3 13:01:58 blr-00 interceptor [0000]: [cluster/reader/[fdos:d7e2:2d90:1904::5]: 12264-> (fd08:d7e2:2d90: 1902: : 3]: 7850. WARN] - {- -} No heartbeat from channel [fd08:d7e2:2d90:1902:: 3]:7850 <=> [fd08:d7e2:2d90: 1904::5]:12264. Closing channel."
```

is there any fix do I have to do in `reLogExtractor` to match all three?

Comment: http://tpcg.io/aa9bWHyA @WiktorStribiżew posted code here expected output: logError but actual output: logNormal

Comment: Ok, the regex group that captured a value last is `logNormal`, that is why you get this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest matching the rightmost status messages, or the substring between square brackets if there are none:

```py
^[^][]*(\[\d*\])?:.*\b(?:(?P<logError>EMERG|EMERGENCY|ERR(?:OR)?|CRIT(?:TICAL)?|ALERT)|(?P<logWarning>WARN(?:ING)?)|(?P<logNotice>NOTICE)|\[(?P<logNormal>[^]]*))]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oTFm4x/2). In your code:

```py
reLogExtractor = re.compile(# parse over "date mumble process[pid]: [mumble." (PID is optional)
            r'^[^][]*(\[\d*\])?:.*\b'
                           # any of the following
            r'(?:'
r'(?P<logError>EMERG|EMERGENCY|ERR(?:OR)?|CRIT(?:TICAL)?|ALERT)|'
        r'(?P<logWarning>WARN(?:ING)?)|'
                       r'(?P<logNotice>NOTICE)|'
                       r'\[(?P<logNormal>[^\]]*)'
                       # close'm, parse over the "]"
                       r')\]')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9ALrOd). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(\[\d*\])?` - an optional Group 1: a `[`, zero or more digits, `]`
- `:`  - a `:` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:(?P<logError>EMERG|EMERGENCY|ERR(?:OR)?|CRIT(?:TICAL)?|ALERT)|(?P<logWarning>WARN(?:ING)?)|(?P<logNotice>NOTICE)|\[(?P<logNormal>[^]]*))` - either of

  - `(?P<logError>EMERG|EMERGENCY|ERR(?:OR)?|CRIT(?:TICAL)?|ALERT)|` - Group "logError": `EMERGENCY`, `EMERG`, `ERR`, `ERROR`, `CRIT`, `CRITTICAL` or `ALERT` or
  - `(?P<logWarning>WARN(?:ING)?)|`  - Group "logWarning": `WARN`, `WARNING`, or
  - `(?P<logNotice>NOTICE)|` - Group "logNotice": `NOTICE`, or
  - `\[(?P<logNormal>[^]]*)` - `[`, Group "logNormal": any zero or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.